# Controlling CSS transitions timing on on elements when preloaded in slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to apply css transitions (using animate.css) to apply some transitions to elements such as fading in, scrolling etc.

The elements however are inside a slider and therefore once I click through to slide 2 the elements have already had their transitions performed. Is there a workaround to this that anyone can think of?

The slide script in question is flickerplate, but I'm happy to change that.

Thanks

Comment: please provide some example code or jsfiddle to work with. Otherwise it will be hard for you to find a solution ;)

Comment: You have to add dynamically the css class that does the transition to each element when you want it to perform the animation.

Comment: Which slider do you use?

Comment: Hi all - the slider is flickerplate. 

Here is a codepen I found for it. I figured if the slide had an 'active' class when being shown then I could assign the css then, but this slide doesn't.

http://codepen.io/lovromar/pen/LFhin